# How to find leading ones/zeroes for 8-bit, 16-bit, and 32-bit integers in JavaScript, using a table-based approach?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

Searched for a few hours on the web for this one, but only found the following. First, JavaScript has `Math.clz32(x)`, so you can **C**ount **L**eading **Z**eroes on the 32-bit value. That is all fine and well, but I want to know how these are implemented.

```js
const trailingZeroesTable = [
  32, 0, 1, 26, 2, 23, 27, 0, 3, 16, 24, 30,
  28, 11, 0, 13, 4, 7,
  17, 0, 25, 22, 31, 15,
  29, 10, 12, 6, 0, 21,
  14, 9, 5, 20, 8, 19, 18
];

const leadingZeroesTable = [
  31, 22, 30, 21, 18, 10, 29, 2,
  20, 17, 15, 13, 9, 6, 28, 1,
  23, 19, 11, 3, 16, 14, 7, 24,
  12, 4, 8, 25, 5, 26, 27, 0
]

function countTrailingZeroes32(x) {
  // Only difference between
  // (x and -x) is the value
  // of signed magnitude
  // (leftmostbit) negative
  // numbers signed bit is 1
  return trailingZeroesTable[(-x & x) % 37];
}

function countLeadingZeroes32(x) {
  x |= x >> 1n;
  x |= x >> 2n;
  x |= x >> 4n;
  x |= x >> 8n;
  x |= x >> 16n;
  return leadingZeroesTable[((x * 0x07c4acddn) & 0xffffffffn) >> 27n];
}

console.log('countLeadingZeroes32', countLeadingZeroes32(0b00000011000011110000111100001111n))
console.log('countTrailingZeroes32', countTrailingZeroes32(0b00000011000011110000110000000000))
```

Counting trailing zeroes on 16-bit and 8-bit integers appears to be able to use the same table, though perhaps there is a better table for these? I guess reuse is good too.

```js
const trailingZeroesTable = [
  32, 0, 1, 26, 2, 23, 27, 0, 3, 16, 24, 30,
  28, 11, 0, 13, 4, 7,
  17, 0, 25, 22, 31, 15,
  29, 10, 12, 6, 0, 21,
  14, 9, 5, 20, 8, 19, 18
];

function countTrailingZeroes32(x) {
  // Only difference between
  // (x and -x) is the value
  // of signed magnitude
  // (leftmostbit) negative
  // numbers signed bit is 1
  return trailingZeroesTable[(-x & x) % 37];
}

function countTrailingZeroes16(x) {
  return countTrailingZeroes32(x)
}

function countTrailingZeroes8(x) {
  return countTrailingZeroes32(x)
}

console.log('countTrailingZeroes32', countTrailingZeroes32(0b00000011000011110000110000000000))
console.log('countTrailingZeroes16', countTrailingZeroes16(0b0000001100001100))
console.log('countTrailingZeroes8', countTrailingZeroes8(0b00100000))
```

So the remaining unsolved bits parts of the question are:

1. How to implement `countLeadingZeroes32` using the "table approach", *without* using `BigInt` (in JavaScript), and without resorting to library functions like `Math.clz32(x)`, `Math.log`, etc.? Only bare basics.
2. How to implement `countLeadingZeroes[8/16]` (8-bit and 16-bit) in JavaScript using the table approach?
3. How to implement `countLeadingOnes[8/16/32]` in JavaScript using the table approach?

[Here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/2c4ca6832fa6b306ee6a7010bfb80a3f2596f824/include/llvm/Support/MathExtras.h#L514-L519) is a `countTrailingOnes`, which appears to just do `countTrailingZeroes(~x)`, so that seems to work:

```js
const trailingZeroesTable = [
  32, 0, 1, 26, 2, 23, 27, 0, 3, 16, 24, 30,
  28, 11, 0, 13, 4, 7,
  17, 0, 25, 22, 31, 15,
  29, 10, 12, 6, 0, 21,
  14, 9, 5, 20, 8, 19, 18
]

function countTrailingZeroes32(x) {
  // Only difference between
  // (x and -x) is the value
  // of signed magnitude
  // (leftmostbit) negative
  // numbers signed bit is 1
  return trailingZeroesTable[(-x & x) % 37];
}

function countTrailingOnes32(x) {
  return countTrailingZeroes32(~x)
}

function countTrailingOnes16(x) {
  return countTrailingZeroes32(~x)
}

function countTrailingOnes8(x) {
  return countTrailingZeroes32(~x)
}

console.log('countTrailingOnes32', countTrailingOnes32(0b00000011000011110000110000011111))
console.log('countTrailingOnes16', countTrailingOnes16(0b0000001100001111))
console.log('countTrailingOnes8', countTrailingOnes8(0b00000011))
```

The main thing is, how to `countLeadingZeroes[8/16/32]` and `countLeadingOnes[8/16/32]` (which might just be `countLeadingZeroes(~x)`) in JavaScript, without using string hacks or BigInt. That is, by using an optimized precomputed table approach.

Ideally we would have a table-generating function for both the leading and trailing tables, but not totally necessary for this post. I couldn't find anything but the precomputed table, no algorithm for generating it yet.

*From the original question, I figured out the count ones/zeroes:*

```js
const COUNT_BITS_TABLE = makeLookupTable()

function makeLookupTable() {
  const table = new Array(256).fill(0)
  // generate the lookup table
  for (let i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    table[i] = (i & 1) + table[(i / 2) | 0];
  }
  return table
}

function countOneBits32(n) {
  return COUNT_BITS_TABLE[n & 0xff] +      // consider the first 8 bits
    COUNT_BITS_TABLE[(n >> 8) & 0xff] +       // consider the next 8 bits
    COUNT_BITS_TABLE[(n >> 16) & 0xff] +      // consider the next 8 bits
    COUNT_BITS_TABLE[(n >> 24) & 0xff];
}

function countOneBits16(n) {
  return COUNT_BITS_TABLE[n & 0xff] +      // consider the first 8 bits
    COUNT_BITS_TABLE[(n >> 8) & 0xff]
}

function countOneBits8(n) {
  return COUNT_BITS_TABLE[n & 0xff]
}

console.log('countOneBits32', countOneBits32(0b10101010000000001010101000000000))
console.log('countOneBits32', countOneBits32(0b10101011110000001010101000000000))
console.log('countOneBits16', countOneBits16(0b1010101000000000))
console.log('countOneBits8', countOneBits8(0b10000010))
```

Comment: Are you trying to count base-10 zeroes or binary zeroes? I.e, would you expect the number 4 produce no zeroes, or 2 zeroes? (Looks like binary... just wasn't to confirm)

Comment: There's a suggestion on MDN to invert the bits, then run it through clz. That will give you a reliable count of leading 1's for a binary number. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/clz32#count_leading_ones_and_beyond

Comment: Yeah this is for counting binary 1's and 0's.

Comment: Do `reverseBits` and `countLeadingOnes` do what you want? They do unusual things. `countLeadingOnes` ignores any leading zeroes (eg it will say that 1 has a leading one, even though it has 31 leading zeroes first). `reverseBits` also ignores any leading zeroes, resulting in almost only odd results (except zero) and  `reverseBits(reverseBits(int)) == int` is in general false this way.

Comment: there are a slew of bit twiddling hacks at https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html, some of which appear to offer solutions to some of your functions...

Comment: They aren't all there, which is why I had to post a question.

Comment: Currently picking through [this](https://github.com/hcs0/Hackers-Delight/blob/2bcb559da638a97f429c19889e6fd7d8601fd5d2/ntz.c.txt), perhaps it's in there somewhere.

Comment: Note also that there are machine code instructions that handle some of these functions natively if seeking high performance.  See https://pengowray.github.io/wasm-ops/, in particular popcnt, clz, & ctz instructions (hover over the links).  The thought being that javascript and good C compilers allow for insertion of assembly language...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table for the trailing-zeroes function only exists to look up exponents for powers of two: `-x & x` returns the power of two with the same number of trailing zero bits as `x`.  This means you can re-use the same look-up table for the leading-zeroes function, as the technique it uses is largely the same; it ‘smears’ trailing 1 bits to obtain a number with the same number of leading zero bits as the original input, and all bits that follow equal to 1.  Incrementing that number gives you a power of two again.

```js
function countLeadingZeroes32(x) {
  x |= x >> 1;
  x |= x >> 2;
  x |= x >> 4;
  x |= x >> 8;
  x |= x >> 16;
  return 32 - trailingZeroesTable[((x + 1) & 0xffffffff) % 37];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and very dirty-JS solution would probably be:

```
function countLeadingZeroes32(x){
    return Math.max(0, 32-x.toString(2).length)
}
```

Which converts the number to a binary string and simply counts its length